# PNG or CSS icon - What has greater performance?

Tags: html, css

I'm dealing with tiny unicolored pixel icons for a website. What solution will have greater performance, a sprite sheet with all icons and theirs hover states or icons that are built with pure CSS.

**[example CSS](http://one-div.com/)**

PNG

```
my_incon.png
```

CSS

```
.icon{
       width:  20px;
       height: 20px;
       Background: red;
       ....
     }
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'd say pure CSS. With sprite's you'll still have to make a call for the image file. Granted the browser should cache it, but even so you're still reading the image file every time vs rendering shapes and color on the screen. Not sure though, time it and see.

Comment: You might consider PNG in case you need to support older browsers. I personally prefer SVG icons rather than CSS. These look more like 'what you can do with CSS' rather than 'what css is good for'

Comment: @turtlepick but old browser don't support transparent png, but divs should be readable for all, right?

Answer (score 1):

CSS will be of greater performance for the following reasons:

- Little network overhead.  Each PNG would have headers that need to be downloaded.
- Browser "paint".  A PNG would require the browser to paint the pixels after analyzing the file.  CSS wouldn't need to as it would just be rendered out to the browser.
- Simultaneous downloads.  Each PNG would be downloaded on a separate HTTP call, but CSS is downloaded once and rendered out.

Answer (score 0):

CSS sprite will have a greater performance. If you test your website using http://gtmetrix.com/ then you will find that less calls to the server will boost the speed of the website and I guess CSS sprite has lesser calls to the server.

Comment: but the [CSS](http://one-div.com/) is read only once and a spritesheet needs CSS as well